# How do I choose which src folder to build?

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have a project with several source folders representing api versions (I know this is really nasty) and I need to be able to choose which one to use when building the war, for example src, src_v2, src_v3 etc.

I'm creating sourceSets but I cannot make it work. This is the current build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    other {
        java {
            srcDir 'src_v2'
        }
    }
```

Is there a way when building the war to choose which src folder to use?

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly add additional source sets to the war classpath. Only `main` is included by default.

```
war {
    classpath = sourceSets.other.runtimeClasspath - configurations.providedRuntime
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get duplicate classes, how can I choose between src_v1 and src_v2, I mean just having one src folder chosen?

Comment: Try setting the classpath instead of adding to it then. I've updated my answer.